# NodeJS - Difference between versions

Tags: node.js, versioning

I have seen that NodeJS v0.12 was released in 2015 but in their main page the current stable version is v5.0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @KevinB apparently why node.js jumped from 0.12 versioning to 5.x in a question of months. (So a versioning question, maybe?)

Comment: This is a completely valid question.  There is a reason why node.js has jumped versions so quickly, and I was asked this question in person today at the office (coincidentally) just before seeing this posted question.

Comment: possibly, but the op needs to clarify. What is he asking? What changed between 0.12 and 5.0? Why it's 5.0 and not 0.13? how 0.12 and 5.0 can be released in same year? it's too open to interpretation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Node.js` has forked to a separate project called `io.js`

`io.js` was (more or less) compatible with `Node.js`, including the internal APIs for native add-on modules (again, more or less)

To avoid confusion, `io.js` used the 1.x, 2.x and 3.x versions while `Node.js` used a `0.x.y` versioning scheme.

Now, `io.js` and `Node.js` merged together again, the first merged versions were `4.x`, and now `5.x` is the current stable version.

Comment: thanks, crystal-clear now!